# no /dev mount for USB device

Tags: usb, kernel, mount, devices

After a recent dist-upgrade, one of the USB device (Hauppauge WinTV PVR USB2) will not connect completely.  That is, whereas previously it connected fine, after the update (4.4.0-89, then 4.4.0.-91), there is no `/dev` entry for the device.  To resolve the situation, I don't know what to look for or debug the problem.

The `lsusb` presents the device

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 03f0:1027 Hewlett-Packard Virtual keyboard and mouse
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2040:2400 Hauppauge WinTV PVR USB2 (Model 24019)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1e4e:0101 Cubeternet 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

and `dmesg | grep pvrusb2` returns

```
[    6.219426] pvrusb2: Hardware description: WinTV PVR USB2 Model 24xxx
[    6.225280] usbcore: registered new interface driver pvrusb2
[    6.225284] pvrusb2: V4L in-tree version:Hauppauge WinTV-PVR-USB2 MPEG2 Encoder/Tuner
[    6.225287] pvrusb2: Debug mask is 31 (0x1f)
[    6.247323] pvrusb2: Binding ir_video to i2c address 0x18.
[    6.259420] cx25840 4-0044: cx25843-24 found @ 0x88 (pvrusb2_a)
[    6.265070] pvrusb2: Attached sub-driver cx25840
[    6.279944] pvrusb2: Attached sub-driver tuner
[    6.468295] wm8775 4-001b: chip found @ 0x36 (pvrusb2_a)
[    6.471846] pvrusb2: Attached sub-driver wm8775
[    6.504049] pvrusb2: Attached sub-driver tuner
[    7.540361] Modules linked in: lirc_serial(CE+) lirc_dev rc_core ipmi_ssif tda9887 tda8290 snd_soc_wm8776 snd_soc_core snd_compress jfs ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm gpio_ich snd_seq_midi ppdev snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore wm8775 coretemp tuner cx25840 kvm irqbypass pvrusb2 serio_raw tveeprom cx2341x uvcvideo input_leds videobuf2_vmalloc dvb_core videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media hpilo lpc_ich parport_pc floppy(+) ipmi_si 8250_fintek ipmi_msghandler i3200_edac shpchp edac_core mac_hid nf_nat_pptp nf_nat_proto_gre nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_proto_gre nf_nat nf_conntrack lp parport autofs4 hid_generic amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 radeon i2c_algo_bit ttm psmouse drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops
[    7.542936] CPU: 2 PID: 372 Comm: pvrusb2-context Tainted: G         C  E   4.4.0-91-generic #114-Ubuntu
[    7.543903]  [<ffffffffc04ad088>] pvr2_eeprom_analyze+0x68/0x1e0 [pvrusb2]
[    7.543903]  [<ffffffffc04b3fe6>] pvr2_hdw_initialize+0xae6/0xec0 [pvrusb2]
[    7.543903]  [<ffffffffc04ba4c0>] ? pvr2_context_destroy+0xd0/0xd0 [pvrusb2]
[    7.543903]  [<ffffffffc04ba55b>] pvr2_context_thread_func+0x9b/0x330 [pvrusb2]
```

`uname -a` returns

> Linux xxxx 4.4.0-91-generic #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 11:56:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**@heynnema**  `dkms status` returns nothing...not a single character

Comment: It looks like your driver is crashing. In `terminal` show me the output of `dkms status`. Copy/paste that output into your question, not the comments, please. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have the info.

Comment: Report the bug to Launchpad and use one of the working kernels. You can boot to a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: pvrusb2, cx25840, and wm8775 are kernel modules that must have received an update that broke things for you. Google them to see if anybody has a current update/workaround for the crash. I wonder if there's a firmware update required for the USB dongle.

Comment: Hum... the web site indicates "The WinTV-PVR-USB2 model 29XXX is only supported under 32-bit versions of Windows.  Model information can be found on the sticker located on the underside of the WinTV-PVR-USB2.".

Comment: @heynnema   is there some thing, in the `dmesg` output, that suggests the nature of the problem?

Comment: @codechimp yes, the last four lines, that show partial information about a crash. To see more detail, you'll have to look closer in syslog around the time of the errors. `cd /var/log`, `grep pvrusb syslog*`, note the time, then go back and `more syslog` or `more syslog1` to find the detail.

Comment: I submitted bug report.  I dug into kernel drivers and found (by change in files size) that there was, in fact, a recent change in `pvrusb2.ko` and none in either `cx25840.ko` or `wm8775.ko`

Comment: Try booting to a previous kernel to assume that it still works there... then rename the current pvrusb2.ko to pvrusb2.ko.HOLD, and copy over the older version into the same directory, reboot, and see if it works now with the newer kernel. (you may have to do a `sudo depmod -a`).